# Async StreamWriter Loop stops writing when BufferBlock is empty

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, task-parallel-library, streamwriter

I recently converted my `LogManager` class from a `static` to `singleton` class, for easier binding in WPF (Though I think this problem also existed before this). After checking every if everything worked, I noticed something strange. The `SaveLoop` task I use for writing my logs to a file and sending them to the view didn't quite work as I thought it did.

In the view they are all added almost instantly, and if I close the application the `SaveLoop` task gets canceled and I can view the logs in the created file. However when the application crashes (or I press the stop button in Visual Studio), the file with the logs contains approx 8-10 logs less than the actual count of logs in the view.

What I noticed is the writer stops writing (in the middle of a message) when the `BufferBlock` contains no more logs, and only continues when there's new logs added.

Is it because the `BufferBlock` halts every async operation in the task because it has no more items to provide?

This is the output in the console when I run the application (The LogStatus message is another looping task that detects is anything has changed in the last 1000milliseconds):

```
12345678
12345678
12345678
1Setting LogStatus=Idle
```

I really have no clue how to handle this problem, if anybody could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

---

SaveLoop Task (Console output is for debugging purposes only):

```
private async Task SaveLoop(CancellationToken cancel)
{
    string logPath = "logs\\";
    string logFile = _startTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + ".log";
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(logPath, logFile);

    if (!Directory.Exists(logPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(logPath);

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 8192, useAsync: true))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                LogMessage logMessage = null;

                try
                {
                    Console.Write("1");
                    logMessage = await _logQueue.ReceiveAsync(cancel).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    Console.Write("2");
                    await writer.WriteAsync(String.Format("({0}) ", logMessage.LogID)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Console.Write("3");
                    await writer.WriteAsync(String.Format("[{0}][{1}] ", logMessage.Time.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff"), logMessage.Level.ToString())).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Console.Write("4");
                    await writer.WriteAsync(logMessage.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Console.Write("5");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(String.Format(" ({0} - {1})", logMessage.Method, logMessage.Location)).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    Console.Write("6");

                    AddLogToCollections(logMessage);

                    Console.Write("7");
                    _timeout = 10;

                    if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("0");
                        break;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("8");
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task canceled!");
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", tce.Message, tce.Source);
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.Message, e.Source);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.StackTrace);
                    if (logMessage != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Log: {0}", logMessage.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Dataflow block. The reason this happens is because `StreamWriter` and `FileStream` use buffering to be more efficient. So, what you should do is to add `await writer.FlushAsync()` at the end of your loop, which empties the buffers and writes the data to the disk.